# I want generate INSERT which include my Primary Key (not generated) by NHibernate. How to map Id column for this?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have table `CUSTOMER` where `CUSTOMER_ID` is primary key.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [CUSTOMER](
    [CUSTOMER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [START_DATE] [varchar(30)] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_CUSTOMER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [CUSTOMER_ID] ASC .....
```

**Mapping**

```
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer> {
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        WithTable("CUSTOMER");
        Id(x => x.CustomerID, "CUSTOMER_ID");
        Map(x => x.Name, "NAME");
    }
}
```

I need to handle assigning of the CustomerID property manually. For example I created new Customer with CustomerID = 777 and name "stackoverflow".

When I call method Session.SaveOrUpdate(customer);
I want NHibernate to generate me SQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO [CUSTOMER] ([CUSTOMER_ID] ,[NAME]) VALUES (777,'stackoverflow')
```

Unfortunately I'm getting errors.

Main issue here is that Nhibernate tries to generate ID for me. But I want to save my entity exactly with 777.

I think there should be way to setup mapping for Id() some another way so this will allow me do what I want.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you do your NHibernate mappints (fluent or hbm) you can setup your ID property to manually assign the id.  I believe the default is to let the server assign the id.

Comment: Thanks.
Answer for my question is to manually setup my ID property with adding GeneratedBy.Assigned();

Like here:

    Id(x => x.CustomerID, "CUSTOMER_ID")
        .GeneratedBy.Assigned();

I think that my case is special.